# Increase the BBOX size but keep the ratio (Lon/Lat)

Tags: postgresql, geometry, gis, geospatial, postgis

I have a Bbox that is defined by the following values:

```
xmin: 11.555333537980914 
ymin: 47.76067947037518 
xmax: 11.995692579075694 
ymax: 48.281587762758136
```

I would like to increase the size of this Bbox but keep the ratio.
One approach I tried is to calculate the middle point of the Bbox and calculate a new Bbox with the value of radius increased by 50%.
The problem: the ratio gets lost.

How could I increase the size of Bbox to 50% but keep the ratio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps [`ST_Expand`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Expand.html) is what you're looking for. You could first calculate the area of the input bbox using [`ST_Area`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Area.html) and then use the output as a unit to expand the bbox.

```
SELECT            -- here you can play with different sizes
  ST_Expand(geom, ST_Area(geom)/2) 
FROM yourtable;
```

Example:

```
WITH j (geom) AS (
  SELECT ST_MakeEnvelope(11.555333537980914,
                         47.76067947037518,
                         11.995692579075694,
                         48.281587762758136,4326)
)
SELECT 
  ST_Expand(geom,ST_Area(geom)/2) 
FROM j;
```

The image below represents the result set. The inner bbox is the one you provided and the outer one was created with `ST_Expand`.

[image]

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b7a1ebd11cb244bcf187789d23b596a7)

Comment: Thank you very much! I updated my question with a solution in R. But the solution is incoplete since the new box looks kind of small on the left side.

Comment: @Andreas I'm glad it helped. Try calculating the area of both bboxes and check if the number matches - a planar representation of data previously calculated over a sphere can become "visually inaccurate" . cheers

Comment: I see :) that makes sense. I'll check.

Comment: @Andreas Consider posting your last update as an answer. btw +1 for that

Comment: added as an answer. FYI Your answer and mine requiere the same run time.

Answer (score 2):

The answer provided by @Jim Jones works perfectly. Is there something PostGIS can not do? :)

I did not wanted to be dependend on PostGIS

so I tried to solve the problem with R. My approach:

I prolong each diagonal of the bbox and calculate the bearing for that diagonal. Based on that data I calculate new edge points of the bbox. It kind of works but the left side of the bbox looks a bit small. I think there is a misstake somwhere but i dont know yet where.

```
xmin<- 11.555333537980914 
ymin<- 47.76067947037518 
xmax<- 11.995692579075694 
ymax<- 48.281587762758136 

###calculate bearing clockwise of diagonal for each corner of the BBOX
######## right bottom, left und top
######## left and bottom, right and top 
######## left and top and right and bottom 
######## right and top, left and bottom 
##bearing(p1, p2, a=6378137, f=1/298.257223563)
bearing1 <- geosphere::bearingRhumb(c(xmax,ymin),c(xmin,ymax))
bearing2 <- geosphere::bearingRhumb(c(xmin,ymin),c(xmax,ymax))
bearing3 <- geosphere::bearingRhumb(c(xmin,ymin),c(xmax,ymin))
bearing4 <- geosphere::bearingRhumb(c(xmax,ymax),c(xmin,ymin))
#new bbox points
########################## left und top
########################## right und top
########################## right und bottom
########################## left und bottom
p1<- geosphere::destPointRhumb(c(xmin,ymax), bearing1, 10000, r = 6378137)
p2<- geosphere::destPointRhumb(c(xmax,ymax), bearing2, 10000, r = 6378137)
p3<- geosphere::destPointRhumb(c(xmax,ymin), bearing3, 10000, r = 6378137)
p4<- geosphere::destPointRhumb(c(xmin,ymin), bearing4, 10000, r = 6378137)

data<-rbind.data.frame(p1,p2,p3,p4)

xmin<-min(data$lon)
ymin<-min(data$lat)
xmax<-max(data$lon)
ymax<-max(data$lat)
cat(xmin,",",ymin,",",xmax,",",ymax)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to translate the box so that its center is at the origin, multiply everything with 1.5, and then translate back. This should be possible with a single `ST_Affine()`, but I'm too lazy to work out the details. :)

Comment: What do you mean by  "its center is at the origin" ?

Comment: Let's look at the one-dimensional case for simplicity. Say you have xmin=10, xmax=11, so xcenter is 10.5. Translate x by -10.5, so now you have (-0.5, 0.5). Multiply by 1.5, giving (-0.75, 0.75). Translate back, giving (9.75, 11.25).

Comment: (Obviously, handling boxes in lat/lon space is a bit of a minefield — watch out for the poles! — but I assume you know that...)