# Best way to create a bounding box from a centroid, a width, and a distance?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, geospatial, bounding-box

I have the centroid of an operation, the width of the operation (assumed to be on both sides) and the distance of the operation. What is the most efficient way to make a bounding box in Postgres with this data?

For example:

My hypothetical centroid is 0,0. The operation is 4 feet wide on each side. The operation is also 50 feet long. What is the best way for me to create a bounding box from this data?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your hypothetical coordinate pair is encoded in a spatial reference system that has foot as unit, such as [`NAD83`](https://epsg.io/7120), you just need to create a 4ft buffer and calculate its BBOX using [`ST_Envelope`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Envelope.html) or [`ST_Extent`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Extent.html):

```
SELECT ST_Envelope(ST_Buffer('SRID=[YOUR-SRS];POINT (0 0)',4));
SELECT ST_Extent(ST_Buffer('SRID=[YOUR-SRS];POINT (0 0)',4));
```

Another option is to use the `geography` data type (`metre` as unit) to create the buffer and then cast it again to `geometry` to create the BBOX, e.g.

```
SELECT ST_Envelope(ST_Buffer('POINT (0 0)'::geography,4*3.2808)::geometry)
```

You can also use [`ST_Project`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Project.html) to define the corners manually and use [`ST_MakeBox2D`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeBox2D.html) to create your BBOX:

```
SELECT 
  ST_MakeBox2D(
   ST_Project('POINT(0 0)'::geography,4*3.2808,radians(225.0))::geometry, 
   ST_Project('POINT(0 0)'::geography,4*3.2808,radians(45.0))::geometry
  )::geometry
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=67c390eb01d38e96ac5352da3e56a96c)

```
WITH j (poi) AS (VALUES ('POINT(-4.50 54.15)'::geography))
-- 1. a random point, e.g. from ST_Centroid.
SELECT poi::geometry FROM j
UNION
-- 2. a 4ft buffer around the point of query 1
SELECT ST_Buffer(poi,4*3.2808) FROM j
UNION
-- 3. an envelope over the buffer created in query 2 (outer bbox)
SELECT ST_Envelope(ST_Buffer(poi,4*3.2808)::geometry) FROM j
UNION
-- 4. Inner bbox created based on a lower left (azimuth 225°) 
-- and a up right (azimuth 45°) corner 4ft away from the POI.
SELECT 
  ST_MakeBox2D(
   ST_Project(poi,4*3.2808,radians(225.0))::geometry, 
   ST_Project(poi,4*3.2808,radians(45.0))::geometry
  )::geometry 
FROM j;
```

[image]

Further reading:

- [`Buffers in PostGIS`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49985343/2275388)
- [`Caculate point 50 miles away (North, 45% NE, 45% SW)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59846149/2275388)
- [`Increase the BBOX size but keep the ratio (Lon/Lat)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67089585/2275388)

Comment: buffer would build a square around my point, no? Instead of a rectangle where the distance and width are different

Comment: @NicholasLawrence no, a buffer is rather a circle. I added an example to my answer that might make things clearer.